# Xcode 7 Swift 2 - Trying to Embed / PreLoad a ZIP file into iTunes Sharing so App Users can copy ZIP to their Desktop

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, itunes

Yeah, So I have an Xcode 7, Swift 2 App that I'm trying to embed a ZIP file into, so that when the user connects to iTunes and their Mac, or PC, they can see my ZIP file in File Sharing window.  I think I'm off by a single line of code, but I don't know for sure....

Here's my code so far (I have this within super.viewDidLoad);

```
    let fileManger = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    var error : NSError?
    var doumentDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true) [0] as NSString
    let destinationPath = doumentDirectoryPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("HDAVSYQT.zip")
    let sourcePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("HDAVSYQT", ofType: "zip")

   fileManger.copyItemAtPath(sourcePath!, toPath: destinationPath, error: &error)
```

I get an error (RED !) at the last line.

What do I do?  HELP!:)

Comment: What is the error you're seeing on the last line? It's hard to diagnose without it. My guess, though, is you're using Swift 2, and therefore should be using the try/catch syntax for errors rather than the error pointer you're using in your sample.

Comment: @Arclite That's definitely it. There's no NSError** in Swift 2.

Comment: Extra argument 'error' in call

Comment: I'm using Xcode 7.3 and Swift 2

Comment: do I need to catch errors at all?

Comment: Right now I'm thinking my code is all wrong!?

Comment: Following is my Objective C version that does work...

Comment: ////////  THIS LOADS THE FILE TO ITUNES SHARING DOCUMENTS //// START 
 NSFileManager *fmngr = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"HDSDNTSCSYNC10sec.zip" ofType:nil];
    NSError *error;
    if(![fmngr copyItemAtPath:filePath toPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/HDSDNTSCSYNC10sec.zip", NSHomeDirectory()] error:&error]) {
  // handle the error
  NSLog(@"Error creating the database: %@", [error description]);
    }
    [fmngr release];
////////  THIS LOADS THE FILE TO ITUNES SHARING DOCUMENTS //// END

Comment: side note.... I do have iTunes Sharing enabled in the plist and the app does show up in iTunes in the File Sharing menu.  And the old app shows the file in the file sharing with the ZIP file, but I can't get the Swift version to work!  Thanks!

Comment: Formatting and use of the Return key in this forum UI is not intuative!

Comment: maybe this is better?

Comment: let fileManger = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        let doumentDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true) [0] as NSString
        let destinationPath = doumentDirectoryPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("HDAVSYQT.zip")
        let sourcePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("HDAVSYQT", ofType: "zip")

        
        try fileManger.copyItemAtPath(sourcePath!, toPath: destinationPath)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your original post by using the "edit" button rather than posting large blocks of code in comments.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 2, `copyFileAtPath(_:toPath:)` throws an error instead of taking one as a parameter.

To properly format your code for Swift 2, you would wrap the throwing function in a do-catch block like this:

```
let fileManger = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
let doumentDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true) [0] as NSString
let destinationPath = doumentDirectoryPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("HDAVSYQT.zip")
let sourcePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("HDAVSYQT", ofType: "zip")

do {
    try fileManger.copyItemAtPath(sourcePath!, toPath: destinationPath)
} catch {
    // Do something with the error. The error object will be bound to a constant called error.
}
```

Comment: This forum UI is so confusing.... and the formatting is confusing for the answers, my code is all messed up, where if I add an ANSWER (even though it's not the right answer), the formatting is automatic and good.  That's why I was putting my other methods in as an Answer, so the formatting is good....

Comment: And I'm so used to hitting the RETURN key, but here a RETURN key is not allowed?  It enters the text I'm typing!?  Bad UI....  Anyway... thank you Matthew Seaman (you did provide that answer above, right?  Welllll... it was very close to correct, just needed a "let" for the very first line of code, or "let file manger = NSFileManager.defaultManagr()      and I commented "//" the second line of code (NSError) and changed the "var" at destinationPath start, to "let" and it works!  I also placed this code on the AppDelegate in DidBecomeActive.... and it's working great!

Comment: THIS IS THE FINAL AND WORKING / CORRECT ANSWER!!!!  

Stupid forum... I couldn't add the final correct answer....  Visit my website and send me email for the final answer that works!   I'll try getting in touch with the "HELP" guys here also, to see if they will let me add a final answer...


Thanks everyone.... 
JOHNAVATAR.com

Comment: All methods I post as answers, are variant methods, for the most part, other answers.... why this forum limits answers I don't know....